# Lesser number of columns of the second row "cuts off" a bigger number of columns of the first row

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

*Edit: Still, when input 3 columns for the 1st row and 2 columns for the 2th, in the output 1st row becomes 2-elemented as the first.

Problem with outputting dynamically allocated number of equipes with separately dynamically allocated number of columns (for number of catches for the each equip)... Namely, if I try to allocate 2 equipes and then for the first equip two "catches" of fish (two columns) and for second equip three catches of fish, everything is o.k.... but if I try input of smaller number of columns ("catches") for the second row (equip) then in the output the "excess" of the first row is "cutted off", so for example if there where a 3 columns input for the 1st row and 2 columns input for the second row, in the output there will be just two columns (indices of numbers) for the every of the two rows.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int *sum;

    int *a = new int;
    int *b = new int;


    cout << "Total number of equips: ";
    cin >> *a;


    // Allocate a two-dimensional 3x2 array of ints
    int** ippArray = new int*[*a];
    for (int i = 0; i < *a+1; ++i) {
            ippArray[i] = new int[*b];
    }

    // fill the array

    for (int i = 1; i < *a+1; ++i) {
            cout << "Total number of catches for " << i << "th equip : ";
            cin >> *b;
            cout << "Equip number: " << i << endl;

            for (int j = 1; j < *b+1; ++j) {
                    cout << "Catch number: " << j << endl;
                    cin >> ippArray[i][j];
                    ippArray[i][j];
            }
    }

    // Output the array
    for (int i = 1; i < *a+1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < *b+1; ++j) {
                            cout << ippArray[i][j] << "  ";
                            *sum = *sum + ippArray[i][j];
                    }
                    cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;

            cout << "All catches of the all equipes: " << *sum-3;




            // Deallocate
            for (int i = 1; i < *a+1; ++i) {
                    delete [] ippArray[i];
            }
            delete [] ippArray;
            // Keep the window open
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<>`

Answer (score 1):

First, don't make your integers into pointers (`int *a = new int;`) unless they really need to be. It makes the code much harder to read, and if anyone has to maintain your code they'll call you an a-hole.

Second, `int** ippArray = new int*[*a];` combined with multiple spots where you do this... `for (int i = 1; i < *a+1; ++i)` are bad. ippArray has valid references from 0 to `*a`, therefore it should be `for (int i = 0; i < *a; ++i)`

Edit: Try something like this http://ideone.com/4egQl3

Edit2: Also the standard advice...

```
{
    std::vector<string> advice;
    advice.push_back( "These will make your life easier" );
}
// No de-allocation needed!
```

Comment: Thanx but when I do that like that then in output instead of the first equip it's counts me from 0th equip. I am begginer in process of learning 2d dynamic arrays. I comprehend pointers and references on the very simple level and again thanx, every consideration helps me a lot to learn something. I will repair my code myself if I catch properly what you explained. But I'm more clever in the mornings. I've searched the whole bunch of google pages for: How to dynamicaly enter columns but for each row separately. Neither on the sites for begginers neither in Stroustroup's books nothing concrete.

Comment: @perpetuum You can't change how you address them, so you have to change how you display them. If you notice in the sample code I posted from ideone whenever you did a cout I replaced it with something like this: `cout << "Catch number: " << j+1 << endl;` for that very reason.

Comment: Thnx for ideone and vector exmp. I've thinked that for this problem there must be a "vector in vector" if considring a vectors? Every info is of extreme value... because neither google neither pdf's always help...

Comment: Check ideone, again when there are less catches in the second equip output cuts it off on the same number of column for the first equip (row) - too?!

Comment: Anyway, it's my fault, logical error probably of my undeveloped begginer's mind...

Comment: @perpetuum I was just fixing up your code. Looking at it, there is a second issue which is that for each row you make, you perform a `cin >> b` and never save that value. So when you go to output the contents later, you no longer know how large that row is.

Comment: @perpetuum You can fix that by either keeping an array which holds the length of each row... or the better way is make ippArray into a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> ippArray` and each new row would be a `ippArray.push_back(std::vector<int>)` and each new column would be `ippArray[currentRow].push_back(Variable Corresponding To ippArray[i][j] Value)`

Comment: I've edited post, so maybe there is some kind of  c/c++  "guru" to give the answer, anyway, thak you on your posting on "ideone" and simplifications in the term of excluding pointers, or editing them...

Answer (score 0):

Parts of your program that have undefined behaviour

- Use of *b before you assign to it
- Access out-of-bounds elements of all your arrays
- Never initialise sum
- Use of *sum before you assign to it

cleaned up, your code becomes

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int sum, a, b;

    cout << "Total number of equips: ";
    cin >> a;

    typedef vector<vector<int> > vvint;
    typedef vector<int> vint;

    // Allocate a two-dimensional structure of ints
    vvint ippArray(a);

    // fill the array
    for (vvint::size_t i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        cout << "Total number of catches for " << i+1 << "th equip : ";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "Equip number: " << i+1 << endl;

        ippArray[i] = vint(b);

        for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j) {
            cout << "Catch number: " << j+1 << endl;
            cin >> ippArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Output the array
    for (const vint & inner : ippArray) {
        for (int num : inner) {
            cout << num << "  ";
            sum += num;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "All catches of the all equipes: " << sum;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just FYI, this question is from 2015, I doubt the person asking the question still cares. This got bumped by someone doing an edit. I would advise checking the date on questions that probably won't be useful to anyone but the person asking the question before investing the time to answer it.